# Is the suspicion of unnecessary travel during "shelter in place" statutes sufficient probable cause for a traffic stop?

Tags: united-states, search-and-seizure, first-amendment, covid-19

Many state governments have declared temporary "shelter in place" statutes due to Covid-19 that restrict unnecessary travel by vehicle. I know this will vary by jurisdiction: but generally, is the suspicion of unnecessary travel sufficient probable cause for a traffic stop and questioning the driver and passengers as to the nature of the travel? Is probable cause not necessary under these temporary "shelter in place" statutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable suspicion for a Terry stop has to be based on "specific and articulable facts", and not based just on a hunch. A mere "feeling" that a person may be traveling unnecessarily would not legitimize a stop, but some concrete evidence could. For example, 8 teenagers in a car repeated driving a loop experientially looks like cruising, which is not in the category of necessary travel. 8 70 year olds doing the same is probably about as out of the ordinary, even if you can rationalize it as confused elders.